# How to send messages that are sniped to another channel? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, message, channel

Whenever a message is deleted, I want that message to be sent into another channel sort of like a log. Basically whenever the message is deleted within a certain channel, I want that sniped/deleted message to be sent into another channel.

**Example**: If a message gets deleted in the channel X, I want the message content to go to channel Y.

**Code**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from tokens import token, CHANNEL_ID

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.sniped_message = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Your bot is ready.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.channel.id == CHANNEL_ID and message.author != client.user:
        print(f'Fetched message: {message}')
        client.sniped_message = message

@client.command()
async def snipe(ctx):
    
    if ctx.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID:
        return

    if client.sniped_message is None:
        await ctx.channel.send("Couldn't find a message to fetch!")
        return

    message = client.sniped_message

    embed = discord.Embed(
        description=message.content,
        color=discord.Color.purple(),
        timestamp=message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_author(
        name=f"{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}",
        icon_url=message.author.avatar_url
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Message sent in: #{message.channel.name}")

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    # assume I would be sending the embed to another channel but not sure how to tackle that

client.run(token)
```

Help is very appreciated!
PS: I am very new to Python and it is very different from JS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Get the Channel Y like this first:

```py
channely = client.get_channel(channel_id)
```

Then you can do

```py
await channely.send(client.sniped_message)
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Also this would fall around here right ` await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)`.